# Can't "margin-bottom" an image in Web Browser Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a webbrowser. I load an url with only a picture. I want to hide the bottom of this picture but i can't do it via "margin-bottom"(In web environment i can do by this way), but try to margin-top and it work.

```
string html = String.Format("<html><head></head><body><img style='width:100%;margin-bottom:-34px;' src='{0}'/></body></html>", "http://s2.haivl.com/data/photos2/20121208/377fafdde8d74135bb31c7e3d51c3a08/medium-b578f6f064994652b5b78709e4896841-400.jpg");
myBrowserControl.NavigateToString(html);
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks